# What is this error with logging out a user with NSUserdefaults?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I do not understand why I get this error:

On logout I call this:

```
-(void)logoutUser {
    NSLog(@"Logging out user");
    NSString *appDomain = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:appDomain];
}
```

And before loading the HomeCollectionViewController I call this to check if NSUserDefaults exist in the Navigation controller wrapping it:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    // Get the stored data before the view loads
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];


    //if values exist then already logged in else take to login screen
    if([[[defaults dictionaryRepresentation] allKeys] containsObject:@"userId"]){

        NSLog(@"userId found");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"userId NOT found");
        StarterViewController *hc=[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Starter"];
        [self presentViewController:hc animated:YES completion:nil];

    }

}
```

This is the error:

```
 2014-04-28 10:19:38.431 App[2675:60b] Warning: Attempt to present <HomeCollectionViewController: 0xba9dd10> on <SlidingMenuViewController: 0xba94200> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
2014-04-28 10:19:38.443 App[2675:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]: value parameter is nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01dff1e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01b7e8e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01dfefbb +[NSException raise:format:] + 139
    3   Foundation                          0x018c4a42 +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:] + 92
    4   Stand                               0x00008769 -[HomeCollectionViewController getHomeData] + 297
    5   Stand                               0x000084a8 -[HomeCollectionViewController viewDidLoad] + 744
    6   UIKit                               0x0095d33d -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 696
    7   UIKit                               0x0095d5d9 -[UIViewController view] + 35
    8   UIKit                               0x00988509 -[UINavigationController rotatingSnapshotViewForWindow:] + 52
    9   UIKit                               0x00ccfe3c -[UIClientRotationContext initWithClient:toOrientation:duration:andWindow:] + 420
    10  UIKit                               0x00884c22 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:isRotating:] + 1495
    11  UIKit                               0x00884646 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 82
    12  UIKit                               0x00884518 -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 117
    13  UIKit                               0x008845a0 -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:duration:force:] + 67
    14  UIKit                               0x0088363a __57-[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:]_block_invoke + 120
    15  UIKit                               0x0088359c -[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:] + 400
    16  UIKit                               0x008842f3 -[UIWindow setAutorotates:forceUpdateInterfaceOrientation:] + 870
    17  UIKit                               0x008878e6 -[UIWindow setDelegate:] + 449
    18  UIKit                               0x00961b77 -[UIViewController _tryBecomeRootViewControllerInWindow:] + 180
    19  UIKit                               0x0087d474 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 591
    20  UIKit                               0x0087d5ef -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 312
    21  UIKit                               0x0087d86b -[UIWindow _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 49
    22  UIKit                               0x008883c8 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 65
    23  UIKit                               0x00838bc0 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 2097
    24  UIKit                               0x0083d667 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 824
    25  UIKit                               0x00851f92 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3517
    26  UIKit                               0x00852555 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
    27  UIKit                               0x0083f250 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 683
    28  GraphicsServices                    0x03bbff02 _PurpleEventCallback + 776
    29  GraphicsServices                    0x03bbfa0d PurpleEventCallback + 46
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x01d7aca5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x01d7a9db __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x01da568c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x01da49d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x01da47eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    35  UIKit                               0x0083cd9c -[UIApplication _run] + 840
    36  UIKit                               0x0083ef9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    37  Stand                               0x0000948d main + 141
    38  libdyld.dylib                       0x0254b701 start + 1
    39  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: I'm not convinced the code you show relates to the stacktrace.

Comment: bz, u got the value is nil

Comment: The thing is the HomeCollectionViewController should not be called at all if the method viewDidAppear (which is being called in the navigation controller wrapping it) is the else result, or do I need to add something else there?

Comment: I think you are jumping to wrong conclusion about your problem.  HomeCollectionViewController is being called - this is evident from the stack trace.  This view controller is calling a method `getHomeData` in its `viewDidLoad`.  It seems that `getHomeData` is attempting to retrieve some JSON data but the JSON string is nil - as per the exception message

Comment: Also, instead of this monstrosity `[[[defaults dictionaryRepresentation] allKeys] containsObject:@"userId"]`, just use `[defaults objectForKey:@"userId"]`

Comment: Yeah ok fixed it, and ok thanks, I will accept the answer if you write it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have made an incorrect assumption as to the cause of the problem.  Your `HomeCollectionViewController` is being loaded, so your user defaults isn't the problem. You can see from the stack trace that this view controller is calling a method `getHomeData` in its `viewDidLoad` method. It seems that `getHomeData` is attempting to retrieve some JSON data but the JSON string is nil - as per the exception message.

You need to investigate this method and work out what is going wrong with your JSON.